# How to use Vee Validates useField with a custom v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vee-validate

This should be simple and quite frankly it was with the older version of Vee Validate and Vue.

I'm creating a custom component that takes a v-model this means of course that it takes in a prop of modelValue and emits update:modalValue.

The documentation for this just doesn't make sense.

Here is my vue template:

```js
<template>
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Full Name</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input
        :value="modelValue"
        @input="inputChange($event, emit)"
        class="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Full Name"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {useField} from 'vee-validate'
import {VModelProp, VModelChange, required, fullNameValid} from 'external-utils'
import { inputChange } from '@/utils/inputChange'
const props = defineProps<VModelProp<string | undefined>>()
const emit = defineEmits<VModelChange<string>>()

const { errorMessage, value } = useField('full-name', [required, fullNameValid], );
</script>
```

Here is VModelProp and VModelChange for context:

```js
export interface VModelProp<T> {
  modelValue: T;
}

export type VModelChange<T> = (e: 'update:modalValue', v: T) => void;
```

Not that it matters but here's input change:

```js
export function inputChange(event: Event, emit: VModelChange<string>) {
  const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value
  emit('update:modalValue', value)
}
```

What I 'should' be able to do is pass props.modelValue to useField but you can't do that.  How do I 'link' the incoming prop to the useField composable?